# How do I watch an AVI file?

Tags: codecs, video-player, avi

I get following error message when I try to play `file_name.avi` file using default video player or VLC:

```
Required plugin could not be found

Videos requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type:
application/x-rar decoder
```

How to install those plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download and install the **Ubuntu Restricted Extras** directly from the **Ubuntu Software Center** which provides support for most video and audio formats (mp3,avi,mpeg,Java Flash, TrueType,Codecs).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the restricted formats codecs. The documentation can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats).