# Unable to play mkv file

Tags: vlc, codecs, mkv

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. When I tried to open an `.mkv` file, it showed an error message

> Unable to Play the file - application/x-rar decoder is required to play the file, but is not installed.

[image: Screenshot of error message]

I tried to open the file in different media players including VLC Media Player. But didn't work. And could not install that software (which mentioned in error message). What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to watch an avi file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329824/how-to-watch-an-avi-file) Run `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` and try again.

Comment: @Kulfy I am not sure. This issue happened when I tried to open an mkv file.

Comment: @Kulfy Thank you. I'll try that.

Comment: @Kulfy Hi, I tried to run the command. But it only showed an error reply. 



E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Comment: Seems some update process is already running. Please wait for a while.

Comment: @Kulfy Hi, I installed ubuntu-restricted-extras. But the problem still exists. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like your file has the .mkv extension, but is a rar archive instead. Does this happen with other mkv files? What is the output of `ffprobe <filename>`?

Comment: Would be careful with a video that VLC cannot play, Since x-rar is pretending to be mkv(or in mkv).  Do you trust source of video?

Comment: @vanadium Hi, this issue happened only in this file. No problem with other .mkv files.

Output of ffprobe was like - [matroska,webm @ 0x557fbb6cafc0] Format matroska,webm detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[matroska,webm @ 0x557fbb6cafc0] EBML header parsing failed

Thank you.

Comment: @crip659 Hi, I'm not sure about the reliability of the source. Thank you.

Comment: Then your problem is solved. It is a corrupt file, discard it.

Comment: Hi, I changed the extension (renamed) of file from `.mkv` to `.rar`. Then extracted. And I got the video. But, I'm little bit concerned that if it is malicious. Thank you.

Comment: @vanadium Please check

Comment: @crip659 Please check

Comment: @Kulfy Please check

Comment: If don't trust source and only reason is to watch, not made by teacher/boss, then delete video.  You will need anti virus software, like clamav or maybe website virustotal to check.

Comment: @crip659 Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`libdvdcss2` -is a library for viewing videos from licensed DVDs.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2`

`ubuntu-restricted-extras` -multimedia codecs, flash player, Microsoft fonts, rar archive unpacker.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Or use `sudo apt-get reinstall ***`

...   `sudo apt autoremove`